# Show and hide forms

Tags: javascript, html

the idea is i have 2 buttons and 2 forms with content in them; i made the buttons to each hide/show a form, like button1 will show and hide form1 when clicked, and so button2 and form2, and it worked, but the thing is when i click on button1 and button2 the forms both show up, and i want something like if form2 was already showed, and after that when i click on button1 to show form1, the form2 will automatically hide, and if i click on buton2 afterwards i want form2 to show and form1 to hide.

#### HTML CODE

```
<hr id="hr1" hidden><!-- HR -->
<input type="submit" id="mngashow1" value="Show 'Add chapter'" onclick="chapterform()">
<div id="formm1" style="display: none;">
  <form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="a.php"" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <table id="tble" width="80%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
            <tr>
              <td>ID</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="id" placeholder="type id" id="id"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>First row</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="manganame" placeholder="add a name for the manga" id="manganame"></td>
          </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Third row</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="chapternumber" placeholder="Add the chapter number" id="chapternumber"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>Second row</td>
              <td><input type="text" name="chaptername" placeholder="Add a name for the chapter" id="chaptername"></td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="Submit2" placeholder="" id="Submit2" value="Save Table">
            </td>
          </tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
<hr id="hr2" hidden><!-- HR -->
<input type="submit" id="mngashow2" value="Show 'Add chapter'" onclick="chapterform1()">
<div id="formm2" style="display: none;">
  <form id="form3" name="form2" method="post" action="a.php"" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <table id="tble" width="80%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
            <tr>
              <td>ID</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="id" placeholder="type id" id="id"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>First row</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="manganame" placeholder="add a name for the manga" id="manganame"></td>
          </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Third row</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="chapternumber" placeholder="Add the chapter number" id="chapternumber"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>Second row</td>
              <td><input type="text" name="chaptername" placeholder="Add a name for the chapter" id="chaptername"></td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="Submit23" placeholder="" id="Submit3" value="Save Table">
            </td>
          </tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
```

#### JAVASCRIPT CODE

```
function chapterform() {
  var x = document.getElementById("formm1");
  var z = document.getElementById("mngashow1");
  var y = document.getElementById("hr1");


  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
    z.value = "Hide 'Add Chapter'";
    y.hidden = 0;
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
    z.value = "Show 'Add Chapter'";
    y.hidden = 1;
  }
}
function chapterform1() {
  var x = document.getElementById("formm2");
  var z = document.getElementById("mngashow2");
  var y = document.getElementById("hr2");


  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
    z.value = "Hide 'Add Chapter'";
    y.hidden = 0;
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
    z.value = "Show 'Add Chapter'";
    y.hidden = 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please dont add unrelated tags

Comment: oh sorry my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <button data-frm="2" class="btnChap">Add Chapter</button>
        <form id="form2" class="frms" name="form2" method="post" action="a.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    
    </form>
    <button data-frm="1" class="btnChap">Add Chapter</button>
<form id="form1" class="frms" name="form1" method="post" action="b.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".btnChap").click(function(){
        /*hids all the forms*/
        $(".frms").hide();
        var frm = $(this).attr('data-frm');
        /*show your current form*/
        $("#form"+frm).show();
        })
    </script>
    
     1. Add Class 'frms' to each form
     2. use button instead fs submit input
     3. each button has its own id
     4. each button has its own property to which form this button is associated
     5. use jquery
     6. hide all forms by class selector
     7. show your desired form by button property
    
    Hope this Helps and welcome to the community :)
```

Comment: $ is a dom selector by jQuery. you neeed to add this jQuery cdn in head tag

'<script
     src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
     integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>' or else your console will throw a $ is not defined error

Comment: also add $("#form"+frm).show() instead of $("#form"+frm); .show() is a method that shows your form